# Whole word search with MySQL on MEDIUMTEXT

Tags: php, mysql, regex, full-text-search

I know this question was discussed a lot of times.
Anyway, I would like to figure out again.

Well, I have table "articles" contains these fields:

- title (varchar 255)
- keywords (varchar 255)
- content_body_1 (mediumtext)
- content_body_2 (mediumtext)

There is an index on "title" and "keywords". However, there is no index on MEDIUMTEXT fields.

I need to perform "whole word" search on all these fields. I am now doing this using REGEXP:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content_body_1` REGEXP '[[:<:]]"keyword"[[:>:]]'
```

And so on. It's okay for 100 articles, but it's VERY slow (2-3 seconds) on 1000 articles. REGEXP does not use indexing in MySQL. What if I have 10000 articles? Is there any way for faster search by whole keyword?

How can I get that? Is FULLTEXT much faster? If yes - how can I design my database? And also what should I do with FULLTEXT limit of minimum characters to search?

Thanks.

Comment: Full text search is a better way to do these operations and much faster. You can limit the minimum characters in `ft_word_min_len` in `my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

FULLTEXT is *much* faster than REGEXP, when it applies.  As a test, I found a word in 4 rows out of 173,979 rows in 0.06 seconds.

You need to do `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD FULLTEXT(content_body_1);` to build a FT index for that one column.

You can combine multiple columns into a single FT index -- if you want to search across all of them.  If you also want to search individual columns, then add single-column FT indexes.

Study the details; MyISAM has one set of caveats; InnoDB has a different set.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using a regexp for a full text search? You could just as easily use the % character and it's probably much faster than doing a regex.

SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content_body_1` LIKE '%keyword%'

This will find any rows where your content_body_1 contains the keyword somewhere in it.

Comment: I don't need to find all words that also contain a keyword. Whole word search means that if you search for "less" you should not get something like "priceless" or "less than". So LIKE does not work here